# Finding a transparent image in a full image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

```
image= cv2.imread('fullimage.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template= cv2.imread('staravia.png',0)

result= cv2.matchTemplate(gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc= cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

height, width= template.shape[:2]

top_left= max_loc
bottom_right= (top_left[0] + width, top_left[1] + height)
cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, (0,0,255),5)

cv2.imshow('staravia', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So I'm using this code to identify this image:
[image]

Inside of this image:
[image]

But i'm getting
[image]
and this on another (same image but different template)
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to check if the image is inside the template or not correctly.

Comment: that's called "template matching". you aren't finding a "transparent image", you are finding a template. -- the issue here is that your template, when you overlay it over the "haystack", is larger than the instance of that critter in the picture. they need to appear the same size or else it doesn't work. you could scale the template down, or the haystack up, if you knew the scale, or you could try a few scales and try them out.

Comment: see this? different scale: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjRwo.png it's about 15% larger than in the scene. scaling to 413x412 gives perfect overlap

Comment: The background is transparent in your template, which will not match well, because it will be stripped off when you read the image leaving a combination of black and white around the figure. So you need to read the input unchanged. Then extract the alpha channel and use that as a mask in matchTemplate(). Also use the BGR channels of the input. matchTemplate will work on a colored image. So you do not need to convert to gray. Be sure your template scale matches the scale of the region you want to find in the input and that the rotation matches as well.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302061/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-screen-ignoring-transparent-pixels/71302306#71302306

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try the suggestions and post an update.