# How to subtract/black-out regions within an image in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am working on a project that involves automating a video game using computer vision. My next task involves separating the game's UI elements from the actual game's field of view. For instance:

We would take a screenshot of the entire client window like so:
[image: client screenshot]

Then we would locate the various UI elements on screen (this is accomplished with template matching, see: [Template matching with transparent image templates using OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74594219/template-matching-with-transparent-image-templates-using-opencv-python)).

Then, we would need to *subtract* the matched templates from the client screenshot to end up with something like this:
[image: client screenshot with UI elements subtracted]

This allows me to perform computer vision functions on the game's field of view without the risk of the UI elements interfering.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
# Let's assume we have already taken a screenshot of the client window
client_window = cv2.imread('client_window.png')

# Here are the three UI areas I'd like to remove/blackout from the above image
ui_chatbox = {'left': 0, 'top': 746, 'width': 520, 'height': 167}
ui_minimap = {'left': 878, 'top': 31, 'width': 212, 'height': 207}
ui_inventory = {'left': 849, 'top': 576, 'width': 241, 'height': 337}
```

How can we blackout the pixels of the UI element bounding boxes from the `client_window` matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by using slicing to set all pixels in a range to black. I thought of this because I knew that cropping an image was a similar process, and both involved selecting a range of pixels:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Let's assume we have already taken a screenshot of the client window
client_window = cv2.imread('client_window.png')
cv2.imshow('client_window', client_window)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Here are the three UI areas I'd like to remove/blackout from the above image
ui_chatbox = {'left': 0, 'top': 746, 'width': 520, 'height': 167}
ui_minimap = {'left': 878, 'top': 31, 'width': 212, 'height': 207}
ui_inventory = {'left': 849, 'top': 576, 'width': 241, 'height': 337}

client_window[ui_chatbox['top']:ui_chatbox['top'] + ui_chatbox['height'],
                ui_chatbox['left']:ui_chatbox['left'] + ui_chatbox['width']] = np.array([0,0,0])
client_window[ui_minimap['top']:ui_minimap['top'] + ui_minimap['height'],
                ui_minimap['left']:ui_minimap['left'] + ui_minimap['width']] = np.array([0,0,0])
client_window[ui_inventory['top']:ui_inventory['top'] + ui_inventory['height'],
                ui_inventory['left']:ui_inventory['left'] + ui_inventory['width']] = np.array([0,0,0])
cv2.imshow('result', client_window)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: numpy calls those things "slices", and this uses broadcasting to assign one pixel value to the entire slice.

Comment: Can you share the reasoning behing the ```[ui_chatbox['top']:ui_chatbox['top'] + ui_chatbox['height'], ui_chatbox['left']:ui_chatbox['left'] + ui_chatbox['width']]```. This should be set to 0 for blacking them out but how did you arrive at that expression